# Property, iVar, accessor method...?

Tags: iphone, ios, properties

I have a couple of classes that I set up properties in.

e.g. a class called `MyDetailCell` that subclassed `UITableViewCell`.

In it I had a property something like...

```
@property SomeClass *someValue;
```

Initially I was using it and storing it within the setter function...

```
- (void)setSomeValue:(SomeClass*)someValue
{
    _somValue = someValue;

    //do something with the _someValue object like changing text or something...
}
```

Anyway, I decided that I didn't actually need to store the value that was sent in so I was just doing this...

```
- (void)setSomeValue:(SomeClass*)someValue
{
    //do something with the _someValue object like changing text or something...
}
```

And then I changed to where I was just passing the setter forward to a subview.  Like this...

```
- (void)setSomeValue:(SomeClass*)someValue
{
    self.someSubView.someValue = someValue;
}
```

So now I'm not sure what to use.  I'm not actually saving the property at all now so I guess I don't really need it.  I don't need to access it to get the value either I just need to set it.

At the moment I've left the property in there as it is.

- Is that OK?
- Is that bad practise?
- Should I change it for just a setter method instead?
- What are the benefits of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that OK?

No.

> Is it bad practice?

Yes.

> Should I change it for a just a setter method instead? What are the benefits of doing that?

I don't see what you mean by this. You wrote 'just a setter method' and you also did some processing in the setter method, which is fine, but you did other things wrong. One is that you don't retain a non-delegate object - you should. You don't provide a getter - that's also a broken concept. There can be readonly and readwrite properties, but not write only properties.

Comment: Sorry, I meant should I replace the property with just a public method instead.  The property is using default values (i.e. strong).  The getter and setter methods are not necessary to be overridden.

Comment: @fogmeister you can do that, nothing special, really.